# Retrieving JSON data from API using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-http

I'm trying to get data from a Web API and display it in a table, but it doesn't work.
I am new to angularjs and i code simple program to get data from the Web API and display in table.but i am not able to get data.

**Module**

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

**Service**

```
    app.service("myService", function ($http) {
        //get All Eployee
        this.getEmployees = function () {
            return $http.get('http://apidemo.gouptechnologies.com/api/admin');
        };
    })
```

**Controller**

```
    app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, myService) {
        $scope.divEmployee = false;
        GetAllEmployee();
        function GetAllEmployee() {
            alert('home');
            var getData = myService.getEmployees();
            getData.then(function (emp) {
                $scope.employees = emp.data;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in getting records');
            });
        }
    });
```

The JS code is included in the head tag of the HTML file.

**HTML body**

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in employees">
                {{ x.username + ', ' + x.password }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The [API URL](http://apidemo.gouptechnologies.com/api/admin) is legitimate.
Thanks.

Comment: are you getting alert message

Comment: Yes i am getting alert message for 'Error in getting records';

Comment: Then the HTTP request seems to fail. You should look at the error you are getting and the network tab of your browser's devtools. We cannot help you if we don't know what the error is.

Comment: The `http://apidemo.gouptechnologies.com/api/admin` is not meant to be used from the client side (using AJAX), it doesn't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set. You should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

Let example a json file in **"data/branchList.json"** directory, And i am trying to access all data from json file using `$http`. 
It may help you to call a rest service aslo. check this example

***data/branchList.json***

```
[
  {
    "branch_id": 1,
    "branch_name": "Mummbai",
    "branch_address": "India"
  },
  {
    "branch_id": 2,
    "branch_name": "New York",
    "branch_address": "US"
  }
]
```

***Controller***

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCntrl', ['$http', '$state', function ($http, $state) {

        'use strict';

        var vm = this;

        function init(){

            vm.branchs  = '';

            loadBranch();
        }
        init();

        function loadBranch(){
            $http.get('data/branchList.json').success(function(response){

                vm.branchs = response;
            })
        }
    }]);
```

In this example i am storing all the data in `vm.branches` variable, you can use this variable in `html` page

***HTML***

```
<li class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat = "branch in vm.branchs">

   <strong>{{branch.branch_name}}</strong>

   <span>{{branch.branch_address}}</span>
</li>
```